# Rails: How to use jQuery to redirect to root page in different environments?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My rails app is called `submission`
I am using  this line in my code to redirect to my app index page:

```
window.location = "/"
```

it is working since my index page is `http://localhost:3000/`

But after I deploy my app to tomcat,

url changed and the index page become: `http://localhost:8080/submission/`

so the jquery code always redirect me to `http://localhost:8080/` which is tomcat index page but not the app index page.

What do I need to change in the jquery code in order to redirect to the correct index page?

p.s. I don't want to change the code to `window.location = "/submission"` because sometimes the app name could change.

Comment: can you tell in which page you are using this statement `window.location = "/"`.

Comment: I am using this line in `_form.html.erb`

Comment: In that case, `window.location = <%=root_url%>` this will work.

Comment: I put this in `<script type="text/javascript" >` tag but it doesn't work

Comment: when exactly you want to execute this line? means as soon as the partial loaded or after any particular scenario?

Comment: I figure it out, it should be : `window.location = "<%=root_url%>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it tough, but can you not use `window.location = "<%=root_url%>";`?

**EDIT**

Obviously this will work only in `.erb` or dynamic files, not static files. To use this in static files, set a global variable in your layout which sets the context/root.

```
<script>var root_url = "<%=root_url%>"</script>
```

Once you have this initialized you can use this anywhere you want.

Comment: I tries this in my javascript tag but it doesn't work, it seems cannot recognize the `<%=root_url%>`

Comment: I figure it out, it should be : `window.location = "<%=root_url%>"`

Answer (score 2):

You would have to output the app root to a tag on the page so that you can then query it via JS/jQuery. You could have a meta tag on the page

```
<meta name='app_root' content='/submission'/>
```

Then have something like

```
window.location = $('meta[name="app_root"]').attr('content');
```

Comment: Does it mean the index page become `http://localhost:8080/submission/` no matter what name my app has?